# download from GCP without using gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to download files from GCP without using `gsutil`: for example, to download the files from :

https://genebass.org/downloads (that are publicly available)

Comment: Can you be clearer on your use case? Do you want to download through the Google Cloud console? Through command line? Through a website/api call?

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide any constraints, so, assuming you have a browser...

Google provides a storage browser for Cloud Storage Buckets. You can browse any Bucket for which you have suitable access using:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/${BUCKET}
```

For example:

- https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/ukbb-exome-public/300k/results/results.mt
- https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/ukbb-exome-public/300k/results/variant_results.mt

Because both Objects represent multiple objects, rather than download each contained object, you will want to select the from the parent Object and click "Download":

https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/ukbb-exome-public/300k/results

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. In order to access the files, we need a personal gmail account. Due to work related constraints, I can not use my personal gmail account.

Comment: You will need a Google identity but it need not be a personal Gmail identity. If you have a corporate G Suite (Workplace) account, that will work too. Unfortunately, the Bucket is restricted to anything that can present a Google ID. Without that you'll be unable to access the data.